# AWS credentials error within docker container in Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins LTS version 2.375.1 running on a AWS EC2 machine. The EC2 server has a role attached to it to provide required permissions. I am running a declarative pipeline which runs certain stages within a docker container by using the docker block :

```
agent {
   docker {
       image "${MY_IMAGE}"
       reuseNode true
   }
}
```

The EC2 host has permissions to perform certain AWS actions via the IAM role attached to it. But when I try to run AWS CLI commands from within the stages defined within the docker container its unable to use the role and errors out with :

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

The code was working with Jenkins version 2.271.1, but has stopped working on the new version.

Comment: You need to give the docker container credentials, either via environment variables or by mounting the host .aws directory

Comment: Used environment variables to fix the issue. Thanks @Paolo